# How to check variable type at runtime in Go language

Tags: go

I have few C functions declared like this

```
CURLcode curl_wrapper_easy_setopt_long(CURL* curl, CURLoption option, long param);
CURLcode curl_wrapper_easy_setopt_str(CURL* curl, CURLoption option, char* param);
```

I would like to expose those as one Go function like this

```
func (e *Easy)SetOption(option Option, param interface{})
```

so I need to be able to check *param* type at runtime. How do I do that and is this good idea (if not what is good practice in this case)?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

See type assertions here:

http://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_assertions

I'd assert a sensible type (string, uint64) etc only and keep it as loose as possible, performing a conversion to the native type last.

```
func (e *Easy)SetOption(option Option, param interface{}) {
    if s, ok := param.(string); ok {
        // s is string here
    }
    // else...
}
```

Comment: Answers should be complete, not just links. Please flesh out this answer.

Comment: note: This doesn't work for concrete types, only interface types.

Comment: This is an answer to the question "How do I *assert* variable type at runtime" not "How do I *check* variable type at runtime".

Answer (score 140):

It seems that Go have special form of switch dedicate to this (it is called *type switch*):

```
func (e *Easy)SetOption(option Option, param interface{}) {

    switch v := param.(type) { 
    default:
        fmt.Printf("unexpected type %T", v)
    case uint64:
        e.code = Code(C.curl_wrapper_easy_setopt_long(e.curl, C.CURLoption(option), C.long(v)))
    case string:
        e.code = Code(C.curl_wrapper_easy_setopt_str(e.curl, C.CURLoption(option), C.CString(v)))
    } 
}
```

Comment: Can this syntax only be used in `switch`? For example if I only care about 1 case maybe a switch is overkill?

Comment: @NathanH Yes, this way works for switch only (tested with Go 1.10)

Comment: Actually, no. The statement `someVariable.(SomeType)` may actually yield another boolean variable which you can use to check if the type assertion was successful, i.e. `someTypeVariable, isTypeSomeType := someVariable.(SomeType)`. It's on the [documentation](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_assertions) about type assertions.

Comment: @bmdelacruz someVariable has to be an interface to do type assertion on it

Answer (score 72):

The answer by @Darius is the most idiomatic (and probably more performant) method. One limitation is that the type you are checking has to be of type `interface{}`.  If you use a concrete type it will fail.

An alternative way to determine the type of something at run-time, including concrete types, is to use the Go `reflect` package.  Chaining `TypeOf(x).Kind()` together you can get a `reflect.Kind` value which is a `uint` type: http://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#Kind

You can then do checks for types outside of a switch block, like so:

```
import (
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
)

// ....

x := 42
y := float32(43.3)
z := "hello"

xt := reflect.TypeOf(x).Kind()
yt := reflect.TypeOf(y).Kind()
zt := reflect.TypeOf(z).Kind()

fmt.Printf("%T: %s\n", xt, xt)
fmt.Printf("%T: %s\n", yt, yt)
fmt.Printf("%T: %s\n", zt, zt)

if xt == reflect.Int {
    println(">> x is int")
}
if yt == reflect.Float32 {
    println(">> y is float32")
}
if zt == reflect.String {
    println(">> z is string")
}
```

Which prints outs:

```
reflect.Kind: int
reflect.Kind: float32
reflect.Kind: string
>> x is int
>> y is float32
>> z is string
```

Again, this is probably not the preferred way to do it, but it's good to know alternative options.

Comment: @karantan According to quux00's code .Kind() is needed. Otherwise you will get compile time error.
https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#Kind A Kind represents the specific kind of type that a Type represent
https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#TypeOf return type interface{}

Answer (score 27):

quux00's answer only tells about comparing basic types.

If you need to compare types you defined, you shouldn't use `reflect.TypeOf(xxx)`. Instead, use `reflect.TypeOf(xxx).Kind()`.

There are two categories of types:

- direct types (the types you defined directly)
- basic types (int, float64, struct, ...)

Here is a full example:

```
type MyFloat float64
type Vertex struct {
    X, Y float64
}

type EmptyInterface interface {}

type Abser interface {
    Abs() float64
}

func (v Vertex) Abs() float64 {
    return math.Sqrt(v.X*v.X + v.Y*v.Y)
}

func (f MyFloat) Abs() float64 {
    return math.Abs(float64(f))
}

var ia, ib Abser
ia = Vertex{1, 2}
ib = MyFloat(1)
fmt.Println(reflect.TypeOf(ia))
fmt.Println(reflect.TypeOf(ia).Kind())
fmt.Println(reflect.TypeOf(ib))
fmt.Println(reflect.TypeOf(ib).Kind())

if reflect.TypeOf(ia) != reflect.TypeOf(ib) {
    fmt.Println("Not equal typeOf")
}
if reflect.TypeOf(ia).Kind() != reflect.TypeOf(ib).Kind() {
    fmt.Println("Not equal kind")
}

ib = Vertex{3, 4}
if reflect.TypeOf(ia) == reflect.TypeOf(ib) {
    fmt.Println("Equal typeOf")
}
if reflect.TypeOf(ia).Kind() == reflect.TypeOf(ib).Kind() {
    fmt.Println("Equal kind")
}
```

The output would be:

```
main.Vertex
struct
main.MyFloat
float64
Not equal typeOf
Not equal kind
Equal typeOf
Equal kind
```

As you can see, `reflect.TypeOf(xxx)` returns the direct types which you might want to use, while `reflect.TypeOf(xxx).Kind()` returns the basic types.

---

Here's the conclusion. If you need to compare with basic types, use `reflect.TypeOf(xxx).Kind()`; and if you need to compare with self-defined types, use `reflect.TypeOf(xxx)`.

```
if reflect.TypeOf(ia) == reflect.TypeOf(Vertex{}) {
    fmt.Println("self-defined")
} else if reflect.TypeOf(ia).Kind() == reflect.Float64 {
    fmt.Println("basic types")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There's yet another way to assert a variable type of the kind "*direct types (the types you defined directly)*" as @MewX commented.
It is by instantiating the type directly in the comparison.

```
// My "direct" type
type deck []string

d := deck{"foo", "bar"}

if reflect.kindOf(n) != reflect.kindOf(deck{}) {
   ...
}
```

The `deck{}` creates an empty instance of the type, in this case, an empty slice of `string` and the comparison works.

Answer (score 0):

What's wrong with

```
func (e *Easy)SetStringOption(option Option, param string)
func (e *Easy)SetLongOption(option Option, param long)
```

and so on?

Comment: because in C libCURL library has only one function for option setting curl_easy_setopt(CURL* curl, CURLoption option, ...). But cgo doesn't support varargs so I made wrapper function in C for each type of parameter. I think that Go interface should be as close to C as possible. If user knows libCURL (from C or other language) I want him to feel right at home ;)

Comment: Late to the game, but I'd argue against that approach! You want the library to feel at home to a *Go* user. (Best example of where direct ports of lower level libraries like cURL confuses people is ...PHP)