# How can I use a parameterized query to search on a column by its name?

Tags: mysql, sql, go, sql-injection

My users should be able to search the database by entering a search term in an input box and selecting the column they'd like to search on from a dropdown box.

However, I can't find a way to parameterize a query in golang such that the column name is recognized as a column name instead of a value. Let me give an example:

```
rows, err := db.Query("SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE ? = ?", col, searchStr)
```

I turned on MySQL logging and this was the resulting query:

```
   41 Execute   SELECT *
    FROM mytable 
    WHERE 'Username' = 'Foo'
```

Clearly `Username` should not have single quotes around it.

How can I parameterize this query? Do I have to write application logic to check each query for the proper column names and use string manipulation to add the column name into the query (perhaps using some placeholder character to find-and-replace)?

Comment: You need dynamic SQL if you want to parametrize table- or column-names. (or prebuild the query as a string, leaving only the *constants* as parameters)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is trying to help keep you safe from bad args (prevent things like SQL injection) but isn't designed to do replacement on anything other than a value. You want it to insert a table name. Unfortunately for you the code is aware of `col`'s type (string) and quotes it because in SQL it's nvarchar and that's how they literals are written, enclosed in single quotes. Might seem a bit like a hack but you need this instead;

```
db.Query(fmt.Sprintf("SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE %s = ?", col), searchStr)
```

Putting the table name into your query string before passing it to `Query` so it doesn't get treated like an argument (ie a value used in the where clause).

Comment: Okay, this worked. I wrote a method to check if the column name is within a slice of valid names for each table. I suppose I can look into dynamic SQL if this application logic becomes unwieldy at some point, but for now it's fine.

Answer (score 1):

You should take a look at this package.
https://github.com/gocraft/dbr

It's great for what you want to do.

```
import "github.com/gocraft/dbr"

// Simple data model
type Suggestion struct {
    Id        int64
    Title     string
    CreatedAt dbr.NullTime
}

var connection *dbr.Connection

func main() {

    db, _ := sql.Open("mysql","root@unix(/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock)/dbname")
    connection = dbr.NewConnection(db, nil)
    dbrSess := connection.NewSession(nil)

    // Get a record
    var suggestion Suggestion
    err := dbrSess.Select("id, title").From("suggestions").
        Where("id = ?", 13).
        LoadStruct(&suggestion)

    if err != nil {
             fmt.Println(err.Error())
    } else {
             fmt.Println("Title:", suggestion.Title)
    }
}
```

Comment: I can't find an example of how to use gocraft/dbr to parameterize a field within a `WHERE` clause. I am using the package for other dynamic query building however :)

Comment: Using the dbrSess.Select, it would just be this: dbrSess.Select("id, title").From("suggestions").
        Where("id = ?", 13).

The resulting sql query would be "select id, title from suggestions where id = 13"

Comment: In my question as well as my comment I think I made it clear I wanted to parameterize the `field` being selected on, not the string being searched for.

Answer (score 0):

> Query or Exec parametrised by name of params. Examples in code, for Oracle, MySql , Postgre ...

```
/*Examples:
  ParamReplacingMode = 0  // no replacing params
  isql:=InitSql(db,"SELECT * FROM table WHERE price+vat>:Sum and country=:C") // by Oracle
  Params(isql,
    ":C", "USA",                    // the order for Params is not bound, you can add params any order, case insensitive
    ":Sum", 130.5)
  res,err:= SqlQuery(isql)          // result: db.Query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE price+vat>:Sum and country=:C", 130.5,"USA")
  if err!=nil {
    fmt.Println("Error:"+fmt.Sprint(err)+SqlStr(isql))
  }
or
  ParamReplacingMode = 1  // MySQL  - replacing params to "?"
  isql:=InitSql(db,"SELECT * FROM table WHERE price+vat>:Sum and country=:C") // by Oracle convert to Mysql
  Params(isql,
    ":C", "USA",                    // the order for Params is not bound, you can add params any order, case insensitive
    ":Sum", 130.5)
  res,err:= SqlQuery(isql)          // result: db.Query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE price+vat>? and country=?", 130.5,"USA") //replacing params to "?"
or
  ParamReplacingMode = 0  //no replacing params
  isql:=InitSql(db,"SELECT * FROM table WHERE price+vat>$1 and country=$2")   // by Postgre
  AddParam(isql,"$1", 130.5)        // AddParam() is the same as Params(), but only for 1 param
  AddParam(isql,"$2", "USA")        // the order for AddParams is not bound, you can add params any order
  res,err:= SqlQuery(isql)          // result: db.Query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE price+vat>$1 and country=$2", 130.5,"USA")
or
  ParamReplacingMode = 2  // mode Oracle to Postgre, replacing params to <$Number>
  isql:=InitSql(db,"SELECT * FROM table WHERE price+vat>:Sum and country=:C") // by Oracle convert to Postgre
  AddParam(isql,":C","USA")        // AddParam()) is the same as Params(), but only for 1 param
  AddParam(isql,":Sum",130.5)
  res,err:= SqlQuery(isql)         // result: db.Query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE price+vat>$1 and country=$2", 130.5,"USA")

SqlExec() is similar as SqlQuery(), but call db.Exec(...)

  Example , add NULL value:
  isql:=InitSql(db,"INSERT INTO table (id, name) VALUES (:ID,:Name)" )
  Params(isql, ":ID", 1, ":Name", nil)     //NULL
  res,err:= SqlExec(isql)
  if err!=nil {
    fmt.Println("Error:"+fmt.Sprint(err)+SqlStr(isql))
  }
*/

type (
    TisqlMode int32
    TisqlAt   struct {
        ParamName string
        Pos       int
        ParamVal  any
    }

    Tisql struct {
        Sql       string
        ResultSql string
        DB        *sql.DB
        Params    map[string]any
        At        []TisqlAt
    }
)

const (
    Oracle  TisqlMode = iota //0, no replacing params
    Mysql                    //1, "SELECT * FROM table WHERE price+vat>:Sum and country=:C" -> db.Query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE price+vat>? and country=?", 130.5,"USA")
    Postgre                  //2, "SELECT * FROM table WHERE price+vat>:Sum and country=:C" -> db.Query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE price+vat>$1 and country=$2", 130.5,"USA")
)

var ParamReplacingMode TisqlMode = -1 //-1 = unknown,  0 = no replacing params,  1 = to MySql,  2 = to Postgre

func indexAt(pStr, pSubStr string, pFrom ...int) int { //Index from position
    pos := 0
    if len(pFrom) > 0 {
        pos = pFrom[0]
    }
    if pos >= len(pStr) {
        return -1
    }
    if pos < 0 {
        pos = 0
    }
    idx := strings.Index(pStr[pos:], pSubStr)
    if idx > -1 {
        idx += pos
    }
    return idx
}
func InitSql(db *sql.DB, sql string) *Tisql {
    if ParamReplacingMode < 0 { // unknow
        _, err := db.Exec("?")
        if err != nil {
            s := strings.ToLower(fmt.Sprint(err))
            if indexAt(s, "mysql") > 0 {
                ParamReplacingMode = 1
            } else {
                ParamReplacingMode = 0
            }
        }
    }
    var isql Tisql
    isql.Sql = sql
    isql.DB = db
    isql.Params = make(map[string]any)
    return &isql
}

func AddParam(isql *Tisql, pParam string, pValue any) bool {
    pParam = strings.TrimSpace(pParam)
    if len(pParam) > 1 {
        isql.Params[pParam] = pValue
        return true
    }
    return false
}

func Params(isql *Tisql, pParam ...any) (added int) { //https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6996704/how-to-check-variable-type-at-runtime-in-go-language
    c := len(pParam)
    if c%2 == 1 {
        c = c - 1
    }
    cnt, i, s := 0, 0, ""
    for i < c {
        s = strings.TrimSpace(pParam[i].(string))
        if len(s) > 1 {
            isql.Params[s] = pParam[i+1]
            cnt++
        }
        i += 2
    }
    return cnt
}

func paramOrder(isql *Tisql, pCheckParamCount bool) error {
    var at TisqlAt
    isql.ResultSql = isql.Sql
    t := ""
    b := strings.ToLower(isql.Sql) + " "
    mMode := ParamReplacingMode
    var p, p1, p2 int
    for name, v := range isql.Params {
        p1 = 0
        for p1 >= 0 {
            p = indexAt(b, strings.ToLower(name), p1)
            if p < 0 {
                p1 = -1
                continue
            } else {
                p2 = p + len(name)
                t = b[p2 : p2+1] //char after param
                if indexAt(" :,;!?%$<>^*+-/()[]{}=|'`\"\r\n\t", t) < 0 {
                    p1 = p + 1
                    continue
                }
                p1 = -1
            }
        }
        if p >= 0 {
            at.Pos = p
            at.ParamVal = v
            at.ParamName = name
            isql.At = append(isql.At, at)
        }
    }
    if pCheckParamCount && len(isql.At) != len(isql.Params) {
        return fmt.Errorf("Different count of params %d / %d", len(isql.At), len(isql.Params))
    }
    if len(isql.At) > 1 {
        sort.Slice(isql.At,
            func(i, j int) bool {
                return isql.At[i].Pos < isql.At[j].Pos
            })
    }
    mLen := len(isql.Sql)
    switch mMode {
    case 1: //to Mysql
        {
            p1, p2, s := 0, 0, ""
            for _, at := range isql.At {
                p2 = at.Pos
                if p2 >= 0 && p2 <= mLen {
                    if p2 > p1 {
                        s += isql.Sql[p1:p2] + "?"
                    }
                    p1 = p2 + len(at.ParamName)
                }
            }
            if p1 < len(isql.Sql) {
                s += isql.Sql[p1:len(isql.Sql)]
            }
            isql.ResultSql = s
        }
    case 2: //to Postgre
        {
            p1, p2, s := 0, 0, ""
            for i, at := range isql.At {
                p2 = at.Pos
                if p2 >= 0 && p2 <= mLen {
                    if p2 > p1 {
                        s += isql.Sql[p1:p2] + "$" + fmt.Sprint(i+1)
                    }
                    p1 = p2 + len(at.ParamName)
                }
            }
            if p1 < len(isql.Sql) {
                s += isql.Sql[p1:len(isql.Sql)]
            }
            isql.ResultSql = s
        }
    }
    return nil
}

func ParamsStr(isql *Tisql) string {
    s := ""
    for i, at := range isql.At {
        s += "[" + fmt.Sprint(i+1) + ". " + at.ParamName + "=\"" + fmt.Sprint(at.ParamVal) + "\"]"
    }
    return s
}
func SqlStr(isql *Tisql) string {
    s := " SQL:[" + isql.ResultSql + "]"
    if len(isql.At) > 0 {
        s += " Params:" + ParamsStr(isql)
    }
    return s
}

func SqlExec(isql *Tisql, opt ...bool) (sql.Result, error) {
    checkParamCount := false
    if len(opt) > 0 {
        checkParamCount = opt[0]
    }
    err := paramOrder(isql, checkParamCount)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    mLen := len(isql.At)
    mVal := make([]any, mLen)
    for i := range mVal {
        mVal[i] = isql.At[i].ParamVal
    }
    return isql.DB.Exec(isql.ResultSql, mVal...)
}

func SqlQuery(isql *Tisql, opt ...bool) (*sql.Rows, error) {
    checkParamCount := false
    if len(opt) > 0 {
        checkParamCount = opt[0]
    }
    err := paramOrder(isql, checkParamCount)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    mLen := len(isql.At)
    mVal := make([]any, mLen)
    for i := range mVal {
        mVal[i] = isql.At[i].ParamVal
    }
    return isql.DB.Query(isql.ResultSql, mVal...)
}
```

Comment: For parametrized sql can use this functions.
Example in code.

Comment: You should add explanation.

Comment: I don't understand what needs to be explained, examples of use are given. If you need something specific, write what is not clear