# "instanceof" equivalent in Golang

Tags: go

I have these structs:

```
type Event interface {
    Accept(EventVisitor)
}

type Like struct {
}

func (l *Like) Accept(visitor EventVisitor) {
    visitor.visitLike(l)
}
```

How can I test that `event` is a `Like` instance?

```
func TestEventCreation(t *testing.T) {
    event, err := New(0)
    if err != nil {
        t.Error(err)
    }
    if reflect.TypeOf(event) != Like {
        t.Error("Assertion error")
    }
}
```

I get:

> Type Like is not an expression event Event

Answer (score 62, accepted):

You could just do a type assertion and see if it fails:

```
event, err := New(0)
if err != nil {
    t.Error(err)
}
_, ok := event.(Like)
if !ok {
    t.Error("Assertion error")
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to abstract this? Is it possible to pass the "type" Like as function parameter? I'd like to test it with several types, given several int inputs.

Comment: @bigdestroyer is there a reason you want to do this in this way? Not saying that type checking doesn't have its place, but it doesn't seem like what you really want to do here. It seems like what you want to do is have an unexported attribute on the struct that indicates its type that has an associated Getter in the interface.

Comment: Well, I want to test that from value 0, an instance of `Like` is created; from value 1, an instance of `Following` is created, and so on. Each one is a different type implementing `Event` interface. I don't want any field indicating its type, just test the "factory" function. What do you think? You solved my original question so I accept BTW.

Answer (score 11):

the `TypeOf()` method returns an object of type `Type`, and you can get the name of that type as a string with the `Name()` method.

I haven't tested this, but something like this may work:

```
if reflect.TypeOf(event).Name() != "Like" {
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is there a way to obtain the name ("Like") from the type Like? I mean, without hardcoding...

Comment: I think it's simpler to use [type assertions](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_assertions) as in @dave's answer.

Answer (score 9):

Late answer but this works fine

```
package main

import (
  "fmt"
  "reflect"
)

type SomeStruct1 struct{}
type SomeStruct2 struct{}

func IsInstanceOf(objectPtr, typePtr interface{}) bool {
  return reflect.TypeOf(objectPtr) == reflect.TypeOf(typePtr)
}

func main() {
  //sample variables
  someString := "Some String"
  someFloat := float32(2.4)
  someStruct1 := SomeStruct1{}
  someStruct2 := SomeStruct2{}
  someStruct1Ptr := &SomeStruct1{}

  // primitive string
  fmt.Println("string <-> *string \t\t", IsInstanceOf(someString, (*string)(nil)))   //false
  fmt.Println("*string <-> *string \t\t", IsInstanceOf(&someString, (*string)(nil))) //true

  // primitive float32
  fmt.Println("float32 <-> *float32 \t\t", IsInstanceOf(someFloat, (*float32)(nil)))   //false
  fmt.Println("*float32 <-> *float32 \t\t", IsInstanceOf(&someFloat, (*float32)(nil))) //true

  // structure
  fmt.Println("SomeStruct1 <-> *SomeStruct1 \t", IsInstanceOf(someStruct1, (*SomeStruct1)(nil)))     //false
  fmt.Println("*SomeStruct1 <-> *SomeStruct1 \t", IsInstanceOf(&someStruct1, (*SomeStruct1)(nil)))   //true
  fmt.Println("*SomeStruct2 <-> *SomeStruct1 \t", IsInstanceOf(&someStruct2, (*SomeStruct1)(nil)))   //false
  fmt.Println("*SomeStruct1 <-> *SomeStruct1 \t", IsInstanceOf(someStruct1Ptr, (*SomeStruct1)(nil))) //true
}
```

Playground ( run it online ) : https://play.golang.org/p/tcQqdzUGMlL

Comment: If you want to compare an interface with a basic type like float32, you could use `if reflect.TypeOf(objectPtr).Kind() == reflect.Float32 {}`. An example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49206944/4206925

Comment: @MewX Thanks to have recreated that useful `IsInstanceof` function. I hope it will inspire Golang creators, and that they will put it as a keyword for the language. I guess they only forgot to implement it.

Answer (score 5):

The closest translation of:

```
// java
if (x instanceof y) {
    // x is a y
}
```

is:

```
// go
if _, ok := x.(y); ok {
    // x is a y
}
```

Answer (score -1):

the func may be need defined like this:

```
func (l Like) Accept(visitor EventVisitor)
```