# golang, use structs as argument into a function

Tags: go

could you please advise on the question.
I just started to learn golang and have already choked with this situation.

For example:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)
type X struct{
    x string
}
type Y struct{
    y string
}

func main() {
    var x []X
    var y []Y

    f(x)
    f(y)
}

func f(value interface{}){
    if(typeof(value) == "[]X"){
        fmt.Println("this is X")
    }
    if(typeof(value) == "[]Y"){
        fmt.Println("this is Y")
    }
}

expected output: this is X
                 this is Y
```

`value interface{}` is wrong type. How can I put different structures into one function and then dynamically define its type.

Is something like this possible? 
Thanks.

Comment: You have a variable and a function with the same name. What is it you are trying to do?

Comment: Updated. Hope, now it's clear

Comment: Are you looking for a type assertion or type switch? Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6996704/how-to-check-variable-type-at-runtime-in-go-language

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use a [type switch](https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#type_switch) if you know the exact possible types. Otherwise you may use the [reflect](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/) package.

Here is code demonstrating the type switch approach:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type X struct {
    x string
}
type Y struct {
    y string
}

func main() {
    var x = []X{{"xx"}}
    var y = []Y{{"yy"}}

    f(x)
    f(y)
}

func f(value interface{}) {
    switch value := value.(type) {
    case []X:
        fmt.Println("This is X", value)
    case []Y:
        fmt.Println("This is Y", value)
    default:
        fmt.Println("This is YoYo")
    }
}
```

play link : [here](https://play.golang.org/p/d1NAcBhwTh)