# How to check if value is a float

Tags: go, types

I want to check whether a value that I get passed is a float number. I have a piece of code that checks whether it is a certain string, or a float number. If neither, then give an error. Here is the code:

```
if sensorData.Passport.Geolocation.Latitude != "gps" && sensorData.Passport.Geolocation.Latitude != "internet" && sensorData.Passport.Geolocation.Latitude != "unknown" && sensorData.Passport.Geolocation.Latitude != //a float nmber{
            fmt.Println("Incorrect option")
        }
```

How do I check whether the data is a float number?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check variable type at runtime in Go language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6996704/how-to-check-variable-type-at-runtime-in-go-language)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> [Package strconv](https://golang.org/pkg/strconv/)
>
> ```
> import "strconv"
> ```
>
> [func ParseFloat](https://golang.org/pkg/strconv/#ParseFloat)
>
> ```
> func ParseFloat(s string, bitSize int) (float64, error)
> ```
>
> ParseFloat converts the string s to a floating-point number with the
>   precision specified by bitSize: 32 for float32, or 64 for float64.
>   When bitSize=32, the result still has type float64, but it will be
>   convertible to float32 without changing its value.
>
> If s is well-formed and near a valid floating point number, ParseFloat
>   returns the nearest floating point number rounded using IEEE754
>   unbiased rounding.
>
> The errors that ParseFloat returns have concrete type *NumError and
>   include err.Num = s.
>
> If s is not syntactically well-formed, ParseFloat returns err.Err =
>   ErrSyntax.
>
> If s is syntactically well-formed but is more than 1/2 ULP away from
>   the largest floating point number of the given size, ParseFloat
>   returns f = ±Inf, err.Err = ErrRange.

---

Check the error from [strconv.ParseFloat](https://golang.org/pkg/strconv/#ParseFloat) and check for an empty `string`.

For example,

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strconv"
)

func main() {
    for _, latitude := range []string{"40.7128", "gps", "neither", ""} {
        fmt.Printf("Latitude: %q\n", latitude)
        if latitude != "gps" {
            if _, err := strconv.ParseFloat(latitude, 10); err != nil || latitude == "" {
                fmt.Printf("Incorrect option: %q\n", latitude)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/4dNsMgRunFp

Output:

```
Latitude: "40.7128"
Latitude: "gps"
Latitude: "neither"
Incorrect option: "neither"
Latitude: ""
Incorrect option: ""
```